# Show dialog before main window

Tags: c++, qt

I have a windowed application, which crashes after showing information dialog only before QMainWindow is activated.

Information dialog is shown only if passed data is invalid, however it might be a user interaction (file select / drag) or passed as argument, which causes problems. When / how should I show such error dialog than?

Note: When dialog is only shown (with show() method rather than exec()) it doesn't crash, but dialog gets discarded right away even with setModal( true ).

Any ideas? Thanks,

EDIT:

Some code:

```
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    QApplication app(__argc, __argv);
    MBViewer viewer;
    viewer.show();
    return app.exec();
}

MBViewer::MBViewer()
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    m_ui.setupUi(this);
    m_viewer = new Viewer_Widget();
    m_ui.preview_layout->addWidget(m_viewer);
    parse_parameters();
    connect_controls();
    connect_actions();
}

void MBViewer::connect_controls()
{
    (...)
    connect( m_viewer, SIGNAL( view_initialized()), this, SLOT( open_file() ));
    (...)
}

void MBViewer::open_file()
{
    // somefile is set in parse_parameters or by user interaction
    if (!somefile.is_valid()) { 
        m_viewer->reset();
        // This will crash application after user clicked OK button
        QMessageBox::information( this, "Error", "Error text", QMessageBox::Ok );
        return;
    }
    (...)
}
```

Comment: Please post self contained compilable example that reproduces the problem...

Comment: `show()` is asynchronous (the call returns immediately) and `exec()` is synchronous (the call waits for the dialog to be closed). Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call app.exec( ),it starts the main message handler loop which is required to be running before you start displaying dialogs. QMessageBox is a modal dialog when used with exec, so will prevent the app.exec function being called. Therefore, it's likely that messages are being sent before the message handler has been initialised and so a crash is observed.

When show() is used, execution of app.exec is allow to process, which is why the crash doesn't happen.

If you want a modal MessageBox at startup, you'll need to launch it after the message handler has been created / initialised. Not the cleanest way, but you could try launching it on a timer to delay the call to exec.

Comment: That's what I've suspected. Thanks fro clarification. Is there any clean way (signal) which marks main message loop has started?

Comment: Not that I know of, but if you're MBViewer is derived from QMainWindow, you may be able to overload the showEvent(QShowEvent*) function to see when the main window is being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try a message box without pointer to your main window like in this example:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText(text.str().c_str());
msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
QPushButton *speed = msgBox.addButton("Speed optimization", QMessageBox::AcceptRole);
QPushButton *memory = msgBox.addButton("Memory optimization", QMessageBox::AcceptRole);
QPushButton *close = msgBox.addButton("Close", QMessageBox::RejectRole);
msgBox.setDefaultButton(speed);
msgBox.exec();
if (msgBox.clickedButton() == memory)
        return true;
if (msgBox.clickedButton() == close)
        exit(4);
```

It works even before creating any window (but after QApplication initialization).

Comment: Yes, I've already tried similar approach, there still a problem when user ends dialog, which leads to crash.

Comment: And did you initialize msgBox without a parent? Probably then you need to file a bug report with the Qt project.

Comment: Yes I've also tried initialization without a parent? Still no change. Thanks anyway.